# Button action and navigation not working in viewcontroller in swift ios

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, swift3

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    self.window = UIWindow(frame:UIScreen.main.bounds)
    let homeVC = ConstDetailViewController(nibName: "ConstDetailViewController", bundle: nil)
    //homeVC.tabBarItem.title = "Home";
    homeVC.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "HomeRe.png")

    // Settings controller
    let settingsVC = LeaderboardViewController(nibName: "LeaderboardViewController", bundle: nil)

    settingsVC.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "search3.png")

    let mapVC = MapViewViewController(nibName: "MapViewViewController", bundle: nil)
    mapVC.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "graphRe.png")

    let userVC = UserProfileViewController(nibName: "UserProfileViewController", bundle: nil)

    userVC.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "UserRe.png")

    self.tabBarController = UITabBarController()
    self.tabBarController!.setViewControllers([homeVC, settingsVC,mapVC,userVC], animated: false);

    let loginVC = ConstituencyViewController(nibName: "ConstituencyViewController", bundle: nil)

    self.window!.rootViewController = loginVC
    self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

I have set the tabbar controller in appdelegate. But now the button actions and other navigations are not working in my viewcontrollers. How can I set the navigation here? Please help

Comment: Check http://www.mysamplecode.com/2013/02/ios-tab-bar-controller-example.html . This will give you full info about your requirements.

Comment: @Amanpreet. I am not getting this objective C code. Please help me with swift code. Can you help me with my code?

Comment: check this http://geekyviney.blogspot.in/2015/02/programmatically-designing.html

Comment: @Amanpreet. I have checked this. I need to add navigation. My navigation is not working.

Comment: Did you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28005108/swift-navigation-bar-disappears-after-programatically-embedding-tab-bar-control

Comment: @Amanpreet How can I instantiate the navigation controller? In story board it happens automatically. But when using xib you have to instantiate? How can I do that?

Comment: Try this self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;

Comment: @Amanpreet. I have set another viewcontroller as root. So that is not possible.

Comment: What is your requirement Like: Navigation->Login->Tab bar->Home something like. Please clear that.

Comment: @Amanpreet. Yes.I need navigation in all my viewcontrollers.

Comment: Here is the Point make rootViewController Navigation then continue your flow. If you do that self.window!.rootViewController = loginVC. How Navigation will show?

Comment: @Amanpreet. Can you show me it in my code?

Comment: @Amanpreet. The below code shows error "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
"

Comment: Can you please show me .xib file of Home.

Comment: @Amanpreet. How can I show that?

Comment: Its late but I have worked on your task. My solution is as below my updated answer please check that.

Answer (score 0):

I have Show you here step by step Points. Please follow that-

**Step1**- AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        let loginVC = LoginViewController()
        loginVC.title = "LoginViewController"
        let VC3Navigation = UINavigationController(rootViewController: loginVC)

        self.window! = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

        self.window!.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        self.window?.rootViewController = VC3Navigation

        self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
    }
```

**Step2**- Create New File of `UITabBarController` like:

```
    import UIKit

    class TabbViewController: UITabBarController,UITabBarControllerDelegate
    {
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
              delegate = self
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        }


        override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewWillAppear(animated)
            let VC1 = ViewController()
            let VC1Navigation = UINavigationController(rootViewController: VC1)
            let icon1 = UITabBarItem(title: "Title", image: UIImage(named: "someImage.png"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "otherImage.png"))
            VC1.tabBarItem = icon1

            let VC2 = SecondViewController()
            let VC2Navigation = UINavigationController(rootViewController: VC2)
            let icon2 = UITabBarItem(title: "Title", image: UIImage(named: "someImage.png"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "otherImage.png"))
            VC2.tabBarItem = icon2

            let controllers = [VC1Navigation,VC2Navigation]  //array of the root view controllers displayed by the tab bar interface
            self.viewControllers = controllers
        }

        //Delegate methods
        func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {

            print("Should select viewController: \(viewController.title) ?")
            return true;
        }
}
```

**Step3** - In ViewController i.e first item of tab do your require things

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        self.view.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9529411793, green: 0.6862745285, blue: 0.1333333403, alpha: 1)
        self.title = "item1"
        print("item 1 loaded")
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

**Step4-** Similarly SecondViewController i.e second item of tab

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
         self.view.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.2196078449, green: 0.007843137719, blue: 0.8549019694, alpha: 1)
        self.title = "item2"
        print("item 1 loaded")
        let button = UIButton()
        button.frame = (frame: CGRect(x: self.view.frame.size.width - 60, y: 100, width: 50, height: 50))
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        button.setTitle("Name your Button ", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(button_Action), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(button)

        func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
            print("Button tapped")
        }
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    func button_Action()
    {
        let nextViewController = TabViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        // and push it onto the 'navigation stack'
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated: true)

    }}
```

**Step5-**  Your Login VC:

```
import UIKit

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.backgroundColor  = #colorLiteral(red: 0.4666666687, green: 0.7647058964, blue: 0.2666666806, alpha: 1)

        let button = UIButton()
        button.frame = (frame: CGRect(x: self.view.frame.size.width - 60, y: 100, width: 50, height: 50))
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        button.setTitle("Name your Button ", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(button_Action), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(button)

        func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
            print("Button tapped")
        }
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    func button_Action()
    {
        let nextViewController = TabbViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        // and push it onto the 'navigation stack'
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated: true)

    }
```

**Step6-** Another Controller i.e abc, I have button on SecondViewController to show Navigation and Tab bar for Subviews. Button will push this view controller.

```
import UIKit

class TabViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        self.view.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.4745098054, green: 0.8392156959, blue: 0.9764705896, alpha: 1)


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: It shows error "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
"

Comment: And when login successful push the tab that is your home VC.

Comment: It shows the same error at this line :self.window! = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)