# I am missing my tabbar after configuring tabbar controller in appdelegate in swift ios

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, uitabbarcontroller

```
let tabBarController = UITabBarController()

    let VC1 = ConstDetailViewController()

    VC1.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "Home.Re.png")
    let VC1Navigation = UINavigationController(rootViewController: VC1)

    let VC2 = LeaderboardViewController()

    VC2.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "search3.png")
    let VC2Navigation = UINavigationController(rootViewController: VC2)

    let VC3 = MapViewViewController()
    VC3.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "graphRe.png")
    let VC3Navigation = UINavigationController(rootViewController: VC3)

    let VC4 = UserProfileViewController()
    VC4.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "UserRe.png")
    let VC4Navigation = UINavigationController(rootViewController: VC4)

    let loginVC = ConstituencyViewController()

    let VC5Navigation = UINavigationController(rootViewController: loginVC)

    let controllers = [VC1Navigation, VC2Navigation,VC3Navigation,VC4Navigation]

    tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers


    self.window!.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    self.window?.rootViewController = VC5Navigation

    self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

I have configured tab bar in my appdelegate. But now I am missing my tab bar. It shows a blank space in the place of tab bar. Please help me resolve the issue.

Comment: Your Problem is still there? Did you follow the step http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41584371/button-action-and-navigation-not-working-in-viewcontroller-in-swift-ios ?

Comment: @Amanpreet. Still I am missing my tabbar.

Comment: Do you want tab bar on login page?

Comment: @Amanpreet. No I don't want a tab bar on login page.

Comment: So, did you follow that steps? As per your requirement you do not need to do tab bar controller task in app delegate. Please follow that steps and let me know if you have any problem.

Comment: @Amanpreet. when  i follow those steps I am missing my tab bar.

Comment: Where you missing your tab bar? In Login Page? Can you navigate From login to home?

Comment: @Amanpreet. I am missing it in all other pages.

Comment: But if you followed that you can see where I am using tab bar controller. I am not using app delegate for it. But you still using app delegate for tab bar controller.

Answer (score 0):

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    let tabBarController = UITabBarController()

    let VC1 = UIViewController()

    VC1.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "Home.Re.png")
    let VC1Navigation = UINavigationController(rootViewController: VC1)

    let VC2 = UIViewController()

    VC2.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "search3.png")
    let VC2Navigation = UINavigationController(rootViewController: VC2)

    let VC3 = UIViewController()
    VC3.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "graphRe.png")
    let VC3Navigation = UINavigationController(rootViewController: VC3)

    let VC4 = UIViewController()
    VC4.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "UserRe.png")
    let VC4Navigation = UINavigationController(rootViewController: VC4)

    let loginVC = UIViewController()

    let VC5Navigation = UINavigationController(rootViewController: loginVC)

    let controllers = [VC1Navigation, VC2Navigation,VC3Navigation,VC4Navigation]

    tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers


    self.window!.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    self.window?.rootViewController = tabBarController //TabBarController

    self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```