# Navigation Items not showing after refactor to new Storyboard including TabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

For better understanding I created a new project and broke down my issue.

Before, I had a Storyboard with a Main Menu and from there it is possible to jump to different Viewcontrollers. One of them is embedded in a TabBarController as shown in the image.
[image]

To improve the structure, I have refactored the TabBarController to a second storyboard as shown in image2. But now I want to add some NavigationBar Items (Buttons). For each Tab I want to have a Button for some actions. Somehow the NavigationBar is gone now in the new Storyboard.

[image]

I have already found some suggestions in different Threads like
[iOS 8 Swift navigation bar title, buttons not showing in tab based application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31436281/ios-8-swift-navigation-bar-title-buttons-not-showing-in-tab-based-application)

From there I tried the code

```
let navigationBar = navigationController!.navigationBar
        navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.green
        let rightButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Right Button", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain, target: self, action: nil)

        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton
```

Which gives me a green Back Button, but the `rightButton` is not showing.

I have also tried embedding in a new `NavigationController` which just results in a double navigation...
Also I tried to add just a `NavigationBar` manually, which also results in a double navigation as shown in the image below.
[image]

Any ideas how I could solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is a good solution or not but it works for me.

Basically the code was correct

```
let navigationBar = navigationController!.navigationBar
navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.green
let rightButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Right Button", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain, target: self, action: nil)

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton
```

But it is necessary to add one thing to the code, adding `parent` solves my issue

```
self.parent!.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton
```